# Python turtle graphics repeatedly goes 'out of bounds'

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to have **Turtle** in python draw a user dictated amount of triangles sudo-randomly. I'm having some trouble keeping my turtle in the bounds I have defined. For example, the bounds of the turtle are

```
border = 300

def drawBorder(border):
    t.pensize(3)
    x = 0
    while x <= 4:
        t.pendown()
        t.forward(border)
        t.left(90)
        t.penup()
        x = x + 1
```

which draws a 300x300 square.

> The following function should - when the X or Y coordinate + the
>   length of the triangle it is going to draw is outside the border - for
>   the first two iterations try to turn the turtle 180 degrees (facing
>   the opposite direction) and move it forward twice the distance it was
>   initially going to move it forward. If this fails to bring the turtle
>   within the bounds of the border the turtle should return to the middle
>   of the border - in this case, that is (150,150). This does not always
>   happen. Due to the 'random' nature of the generation, most times the
>   turtle ends up outside of the border, though sometimes it does draw
>   all triangles within the border.

```
 if t.xcor() + lengthOfTriangle > border or t.xcor() + lengthOfTriangle < 0 or \
    t.ycor() + lengthOfTriangle > border or t.ycor() + lengthOfTriangle < 0:
x = 0
while x < 2:
    t.penup()
    t.left(180)
    t.forward(2 * lengthOfTriangle)
    t.pendown()
    x = x + 1
else:
    t.penup()
    if t.xcor() > border:
        t.seth(180)
    if t.xcor() < border:
        t.seth(0)
    t.forward(t.xcor() - (t.xcor() + border/2))
    if t.ycor() > border:
        t.seth(90)
    if t.ycor() < border:
        t.seth(270)
    t.forward(t.ycor() - (t.ycor() + border/2))

print("Turtle was going to be out of bounds. Xcor would be: ", t.xcor() + lengthOfTriangle,
      ". And Ycor would be: ", t.ycor() + lengthOfTriangle)
return drawFigureRec(numTriangles, lengthOfTriangle=random.randint(1, 20),
                     distanceTriangle=random.randint(1, 40),
                     angleTriangle=random.randint(0, 360), sum=sum)
```

If you need context for the function variables and such I have linked a pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/J3jhk6Ur).

Here is a picture showing the problem.[The turtle should stay within the 'bounds' (red square), but goes outside as shown by the console's output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvZM9.png)

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by "having some trouble keeping my turtle in the bounds"?

Comment: @martineau I added a picture to the original post for clarification.

Comment: Sorry, no, image added really doesn't help much. What does  being in bounds mean precisely? What should happen when the turtle goes out of those bounds and what's currently happening instead? You should also post enough code (but only the minimal amount needed) **in your question** to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @martineau I have clarified the question even further. In short, when the turtle goes outside the drawn bounds it should first try to reverse back into the bounds. If it fails to reverse into the bounds then it will return to the middle of the border (in this case 150,150).

Comment: OK, that clarifies things somewhat—at least enough for me to see one problem...which is that when `drawFigureRec()` calls itself when the Turtle was going to be out of bounds and passes itself different random arguments, it's assuming they're going to produce a different result. In fact, the same out-of-bounds condition can reoccur which causes it to keep calling itself over and over. BTW, to easily get reproducible results for testing I suggest you add a `random.seed(42)` (where `42` is some integer constant) near the beginning of your script before any `random.randint()` calls are made.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code.  For example, this boundary checking logic completely ignores the current heading of the turtle:

```
   if t.xcor() + lengthOfTriangle > border or ... t.ycor() + lengthOfTriangle > border or ...
```

I.e. it always assumes +45 degrees so can't work.  You can either do
the trigonometry or, simply move the turtle to the new postion and
test if it's out of bounds.  If out of bounds, you can move it back,
adjust and try again.  The `turtle.undo()` method is helpful here.

Your `drawFigure*()` functions sometimes explicitly return values,
sometimes not.  Once a function explicitly returns a value, it should
explictly return one from all points of exit, not implicitly return
`None` sometimes.

Your square border has five sides:

```
   x = 0
   while x <= 4:
```

since the last one overdraws the first, this isn't visually obvious.

Let's try a simpler iterative approach where we use `turtle.circle()` to draw our triangles but think of each triangle as a circle when determining if it's in bounds.  We'll also center our drawing instead of just using the upper right quadrant and positive numbers:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

NUMBER_TRIANGLES = 80
PEN_SIZE = 3
BORDER = 300

def drawBorder(border):
    turtle.pensize(PEN_SIZE)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(-border/2, -border/2)
    turtle.pendown()

    for _ in range(4):
        turtle.forward(border)
        turtle.left(90)

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.home()

def drawFigure(numTriangles):
    if not 0 < numTriangles < 500:
        exit("Number of triangles is out of range!")

    for _ in range(numTriangles):

        radius = randint(3, 20)
        distance = randint(2, 60)

        turtle.forward(distance)

        while not(radius - BORDER/2 < turtle.xcor() < BORDER/2 - radius and radius - BORDER/2 < turtle.ycor() < BORDER/2 - radius):
            turtle.undo()  # undo last forward()
            turtle.left(37)  # rotate and try again (relative prime angle)
            distance += 1  # increase distance slightly on failure
            turtle.forward(distance)

        angle = randint(1, 360)
        turtle.setheading(angle)

        turtle.right(90)  # turtle represents center so need to adjust
        turtle.forward(radius)  # as turtle.circle() doesn't think that way
        turtle.left(90)

        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.circle(radius, steps=3)
        turtle.penup()

        turtle.left(90)  # undo adjustment to move turtle back to center
        turtle.forward(radius)
        turtle.right(90)

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')

drawBorder(BORDER)
drawFigure(NUMBER_TRIANGLES)

turtle.hideturtle()

screen.tracer(True)
screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

I'll not include the recursive equivalent as this really isn't a recursive problem.  You can force it to be one as your assignment requires.